# Tengo una Drum machine y y un estado para cambiar el audio, lo que quiero es que cada vez que haga click en uno de mis botones se reproduzca el audio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-hooks, audio

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import heater from './Heater-1.mp3'


function App() {
  const [power, setPower] = useState(false);
  
  const [audioSrc, setAudioSrc] = useState("");

  

  const turnOn = () => {
    setPower(!power);
  };

  

  const handleClickButton = (e) => {
    const buttonId = e.target.id;
    if (power) {
      switch (buttonId) {
        case "Q":
          setAudioSrc(heater);
          break;
        case "W":
          setAudioSrc("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3");
          break;
        case "E":
          setAudioSrc("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3");
          break;
        case "A":
          setAudioSrc("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3");
          break;
        case "S":
          setAudioSrc("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3");
          break;
        case "D":
          setAudioSrc("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3");
          break;
        case "Z":
          setAudioSrc("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3");
          break;
        case "X":
          setAudioSrc("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3");
          break;
        case "C":
          setAudioSrc("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3");
          break;
        default:
          setAudioSrc("");
          break;
      }
      audioSrc.play()
    }
  };
```

El `handleClickButton` lo que hace es si el boton para encender la Drum Machine es True, puedo pulsar las teclas y reproducir los clip de canciones, cada que pulso una diferente cambia el estado, eso funciona correctamente

En el `audioSrc.play()` deberia reproducir el audio cada vez que hago click en un button, pero al parecer creo que es la parte del codigo que no va, porque no suena nada, no reproduce nada!

```
  return (
    <div className="drum-machine">
      <div className="buttons">
        <button id="Q" className="drum-pad" onClick={handleClickButton}>
          Q
        </button>
        <button id="W" className="drum-pad" onClick={handleClickButton}>
          W
        </button>
        <button id="E" className="drum-pad" onClick={handleClickButton}>
          E
        </button>
        <button id="A" className="drum-pad" onClick={handleClickButton}>
          A
        </button>
        <button id="S" className="drum-pad" onClick={handleClickButton}>
          S
        </button>
        <button id="D" className="drum-pad" onClick={handleClickButton}>
          D
        </button>
        <button id="Z" className="drum-pad" onClick={handleClickButton}>
          Z
        </button>
        <button id="X" className="drum-pad" onClick={handleClickButton}>
          X
        </button>
        <button id="C" className="drum-pad" onClick={handleClickButton}>
          C
        </button>
      </div>
      
      <div className="functions">
        <label className="switch">
          <h1>Power</h1>
          <input type="checkbox" id="miInterruptor" onClick={turnOn} />
          <span class="slider"></span>
        </label>
        <div className="buttons-name"></div>
        <input type="range" />
        <label className="switch2">
          <h1>Bank</h1>
          <input type="checkbox" id="miInterruptor2" />
          <span className="slider2"></span>
        </label>
        <audio id="audio" >


          <source src={audioSrc} type="audio/mpeg" />
        </audio>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

el `<source>` almacena el nuevo estado que es asignado para que lo use el audio y se reproduzca cada vez que hago click en alguno de los buttons mientras la Drum Machine este encendida, aqui `audioSrc` funciona correctamente, lo unico que veo que puede estar mal es `audioSrc.play()` no se si ese codigo es correcto, o estoy haciendo algo mal

Tambien quisiera saber como hacer para que cada vez que pulso una tecla del teclado con el id de los botones se reproduzca tambien el audio clip